# Не могу обновить список

Tags: android, recyclerview, kotlin, android-data-binding

Использую `DataBinding` для связывания. Но не могу обновить адаптер с помощью `notifyDataSetChanged()`. Лист обновляеться и колбэк вызываеться.
Код:

```
private lateinit var binding : ReportsFragmentBinding
private var reportList : List<Report> = emptyList()
private var mViewModel : ReportsViewModel? = null
...
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.reports_fragment, container, false)
    binding.reportsRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
    binding.reportsRecyclerView.adapter = ReportAdapter(reportList)
    return binding.root
}

override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    mViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ReportsViewModel::class.java)

    mViewModel?.getReportListObservable()?.observe(this, Observer<List<Report>> { list ->
            list?.let {
                reportList = list
                binding.reportsRecyclerView.adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
        })
    }
```

При этом, если вместо `notifyDataSetChanged()` каждый раз указываю списку адаптер то все работает. Есть ли вообще способы обновления списка способами `databinding`а?

Comment: вообще паттерн MVVM предполагает прямую связь между данными и вью, то есть изменения данных тут же приводят к изменениям в вью, без дополнительных движений со сторны программиста и по идее никакие notifyDataChanged() здесь не нужны, иначе зачем вообще использовать этот более сложный в реализации паттерн

Comment: @pavloff, знаю, но вот как заставить  recycler view обновляться не пойму.

Comment: Если цель ваших усилий - автоматическое обновление списка при изменении данных, то рекомендую использовать "классическую" архитектуру и [этот адаптер](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/recyclerview/extensions/ListAdapter) (v7.ListAdapter) из библиотеки поддержки, тем более вы и так используете Architecture Components - такая реализация намного проще и эффективнее, чем data binding. Особенностью адаптера является то, что обращение к данным осуществляется только через метод `getItem()` и реализация DiffUtil для обновления только измененных айтемов, а не всего списка.

Comment: @pavlofff, под "классической" вы имеете ввиду MVC?

Comment: реализация, как самого обычного списка RecyclerView, да MVC. Разница только в релизации колбэка DiffUtill и подключении обсервера адаптера к данным для отслеживания измений. Я в свое время тоже пытался использовать андроидовский биндинг (при разработке под винду привык к MVVM), но столкнулся со слишком большим количеством непонятного в происходящем и багов, что решил оставить это, но может кто то более проникшийся этой темой решит вашу проблему все же.